# relation between the number of real roots of the derivative and the original polynomial

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots

If the derivative of polynomial  has n real roots then can we conclude that the original polynomial has to have  n+1 real roots?

Comment: Consider $f'(x)=2x$.

Comment: For a slightly more spectacular example, see $f(x) = x^4 - x^2 + 1$.

Comment: @GitGud Yes, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $f(x)=x^2+1$ provides a counterexample.

Comment: Then If the derivative of polynomial has n real roots then cannot tell anything about the number of real roots of the original polynomial, isn't it?

Comment: That is correct.